# How to display user@hostname in SSHD password prompt

Tags: ssh, prompt

When I SSH to a server, the prompt sometimes displays my user and the hostname of the server:

```
xavier@local:~$ ssh server1
xavier@server1's password:
```

Sometimes all I get is `Password:`

```
xavier@local:~$ ssh server2
Password:
```

Which is less convenient when tunneling (difficult to know if I have to enter the password for the second server or if I need to repeat the first one because I made a mistake for instance), and also when using different usernames (did I forget to set the correct one in `.ssh/config`?).

Typically I find that Debian/Ubuntu will prompt with `user@hostname's password:`, whereas I see `Password:` on OpenSUSE/SLES/Mac servers.

Obviously the servers are configured differently, but I couldn't find what causes this difference. How can I configure the ssh server to display the user and hostname in the prompt? Or maybe I can do it client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Investigating a bit further, it appears that the `user@server's password` prompt is used for password authentication, whereas the `Password:` prompt is the displayed for keyboard-interactive authentication. I wasn't aware that these two methods existed. [They look pretty similar as they will typically both ask for a password](https://superuser.com/questions/894608/ssh-o-preferredauthentications-whats-the-difference-between-password-and-k).

So the trick is to:

1. Make sure password authentication is enabled on the server. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

   ```
   PasswordAuthentication yes
   ```
2. On the client side, set `password` as the preferred method

   ```
   ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password server2
   ```

   It is sensible to add the `keyboard-interactive` method to the list in case the server has PasswordAuthentication disabled

   ```
   ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password,keyboard-interactive server2
   ```

   I ended up adding the following to my `.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host *
           ServerAliveInterval 120
           VerifyHostKeyDNS yes
           PreferredAuthentications publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
   ```

I am now getting the `user@server's password:` prompt on all hosts.

Comment: And then there is `Banner /etc/ssh/sshd-banner` for a disclaimer / greet before authentication.